# Build apk using buildozer and kivy Error with gradlew (new project)

Tags: android, python-2.7, kivy, buildozer

I have been able to build an `.apk` file by `kivy` and `python2.7` using `buildozer`, and the app works fine on phone-device. After a while, i started a new project in a new folder (together with new `main.py`), but when i do `buildozer android debug`, the Error *attached* keeps coming out, something with `gradlew`. In my previous builds, this never happens.

In this new `main.py`, i previously use `numpy` module, but this module cause Error also in the build-up. So i removed it and rewrite the code. Now another Error occurs (the Error because `gradlew`).

I have tried added `android` in the requirements. Does not work. (although i prefer to use the default `buildozer.spec`).

I appreciate some inputs on this.

*Also, i found some official resources, either from Github or the buildozer site are a bit inconsistent. Is there a detail resource such that i may install `buildozer` correctly, also the guide for the `buildozer.specs`?
I even not fully remember why the previous app works well..because i also bumped into several problems before the 1st App works fine.

** When i `debug` the new `main.py` in the old folder, the build process succeed.**
** (I also use the same `package.name` and `package.domain` as the 1st App) **

Thanks in advance.

```
      STDERR:


[INFO]:    STDOUT:
    Unzipping /home/kivy/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/2n0i7hqatcbtk57vvql575dbap/gradle-3.3-all.zip to /home/kivy/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/2n0i7hqatcbtk57vvql575dbap   
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)    
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)   
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)   
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)   
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:157)   
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:26)   
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:67)   
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:44)   
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65) 
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)   
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:126)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:56)
[INFO]:    STDERR:

[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /home/kivy/Desktop/blablaapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp && ./gradlew assembleDebug

[WARNING]: ERROR: ./gradlew failed!
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --debug --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name myapp --name 'My Application' --version 0.1 --package org.test.myapp --android_api 19 --minsdk 9 --private /home/kivy/Desktop/sudoku_newbie/.buildozer/android/app --orientation portrait --window --copy-libs --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir=/home/kivy/Desktop/sudoku_newbie/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

This error mostly occurs when you've interrupted the system when Gradle was downloading.

You can simply fix this by manually downloading gradle from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

Then replace the `gradle-4.4-all.zip.part` in `/your/home/path/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.4-all/4th6d42q1kgladv9hkn2iehgi5` with the new dowloaded file

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow! Please explain your answer with more detail so other users can receive it well.

Comment: I want to add yo must delete .lck file

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem to solve mine I downloaded an earlier version of buildozer and it worked

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).